# Buffer Overflow exploit , overwriting function parameters including return address

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, exploit

Assume we have a function

```
foo(char *name,int id)
{  
 printf ("%s%d",name,id);
}
```

Using buffer overflow, we replace the return address on the stack with foo function address. I was able to accomplish this.

How do i overflow function arguments too ? foo take two arguments , can someone please help me to understand how can i overflow these arguments using buffer overflow.

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite the arguments? Normally, you would just overwrite the return address and address some instructions that would lead to a jump to your shellcode.

Comment: yes your right ,but my purpose is not to jump to a shell code. Rather see if its possible to overwrite function arguments in the stack.

Comment: to be more clear , when the function is called - can i give my own custom parameters to that function ?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes , arguments are pushed onto the stack when the function is called but then successful overwrite depends on the layout of the stack . Also from what your objective is you have to do it in a way so as not to corrupt the data in between.

The above code has another vulnerability too , think about it .

Comment: Yes, it has format string vulnerability. I would like to learn overwriting layout of the stack.|

I tried below input , but i'm facing segmentation faults...

"Lenght of the string buffer" + " EBP " + "Return address" + "Arg1" + "Arg2 "